# Flash ProgressEvent Not Showing Total Size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, file, size, progress

I'm using a ProgressEvent in Flash to determine how long something will take to download. I've got this:

```
        progress = event.target.bytesLoaded/event.target.bytesTotal;
```

to set a percentage.

After some scratching of my head, I did a trace on the two values - and it turns out that "event.target.bytesTotal" is always equaling zero.

I can't find any mention of this in the Flex/AS3/Flash API. Any hints on how to get bytesTotal to work?

(I'm currently reading from a PHP file on the webserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 progress = event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal;
```

bytesTotal / bytesLoaded should be a property of the progress event.

Also... I had this problem yesterday, and it totally stumped me until I thought to check the file I was loading, and it ended up being corrupt and 0 bytes - so double check that too:)

Comment: Hm, your code produces the exact same effect (bytesLoaded works fine, bytesTotal always reports 0). I know the file is fine because it eventually downloads and works. :)

Comment: Really strange. If you try the code with another php file, or something else, does it do the same thing?

Comment: If you check the urlloader.bytesTotal (or whatever you're using) property of whatever you're loading, is that also zero?

Comment: Maybe the file you're loading doesn't have Content-Length header set somehow?

Answer (score 4):

We've solved this issue on our server by disabling the compression of some file types.

The bytesTotal was 0 for files that were being served compressed. This compression happens on-the-fly and that is why the server cannot give the size of the file (because it doesn't know it yet). Removing the compression solved it.