# Swf game loading infinity?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading

i tried to create a swf game. It worked perfectly on my old host and domain. But when i moved my game to new host and domain, it doesn't show loading progress on firefox and with google chrome, it stops working with 'Loading Infinity%'.

Here is my game: http://afcvn.myarsenal.net/afcvn/swf_games/game_matching.swf

And this is my loading code and i export classes in frame 2:

```
stop();

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);

function loading(e:Event):void {

    var total:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    progressBar.scaleX = loaded/total;
    loader_info.text = "Loading "+Math.floor((loaded/total)*100)+ "%";

    if (total == loaded) {
        play();
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loading);
    }

}
```

I added a crossdomain.xml: http://afcvn.myarsenal.net/crossdomain.xml

Can anybody help? Highly appreciate! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858882/224734). (turn off server compression on swf files)

And try to avoid division by zero (Flash allows it but the outcome is Infinity). If bytesLoaded==0 your loading code will stop immediately because bytesTotal==0 too then.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Your answer really make my day. :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems the headers in your request to load the SWF are missing the `Content-Length` making Flash not able to calculate your percentage. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with your swf or on your server but now you know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the compression on all file types might affect optimization of overall page.

Just disable the compression on .swf on .htaccess file:

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .swf$ no-gzip dont-vary

Answer (score 0):

frankhermes answer is true, this can be solved by turning off server compression on swf files.

Not knowing how to do this was my next problem so I researched and came up with the following solution.

To disable gzip compression of just SWFs on an Apache server, add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.swf$">
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```